# How to use sax to parse and xml file containing user comments

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I'm using sax to parse an xml file and it works BUT its only partly parsing between the tag I'm interested in

```
     try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                boolean bcomm = false;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("COMMENT")) {
                        bcomm = true;
                        }                           
        }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (bcomm) {                        
                        review = new String(ch, start, length) + "\n";                        
                        bcomm = false;
                    }
                }
            };
```

this is some of the output I get:

Excellent protection for and from my teen

I bought a first-generation Windows XP tablet in 2002 that worked really well with a stylus and writing: I take extensive notes and do frequent trainings where using electronic

This is a great product. It

**But I want to get:**

Excellent protection for and from my teen's Kindle.

I bought a first-generation Windows XP tablet in 2002 that worked really well with a stylus and writing: I take extensive notes and do frequent trainings where using electronic "whiteboards" on a computer is an advantage as the documents I create can be shared immediately. When that machine wimped out 4 years ago, I started searching for its replacement from Windows Vista/7, iPad #1/2/3 gen#, Android ... nothing supported the combination of handwriting, ease of stylus use, speed and ability to easily share the created documents until now. Windows 8 really shines in Surface Pro as does Office 2013. Both the OS and the application take advantage of the processing power and additional memory over the Surface RT. Taking notes in OneNote is a breeze -- no lag or choppiness in capturing what I write and it's great having a full Outlook client available again. I'll be interested to see how weight plays over time -- but compared to my 2002 hybrid or the brick of an "elite" 2012 laptop my company gives me, this thing is light. I also gave it 4 for ease of use for Windows 8 -- while I have been using Windows 8 for over a year and it is definitely a much better experience on a touch device, it still lacks ease when compared to iOS/Android tablets. As for native Windows apps compared to iOS -- there are only 2 apps I regularly use on iOS that are not on Windows 8 #History Channel Civil War and Hay Day#; if it weren't for those, my iPad 3 would be retired to the kids.

This is a great product. It's like there are 3 cases built into one, because of the two additional color coded straps that are included with this product. I like this product very much

I think it has something to do with punctuation characters...please help???

Answer (score 0):

Store the char data to a buffer declared outside of method.

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
//   if (bcomm) {   
       buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
       bcomm = false;
//   }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that but is just appending the different comments together, but still stopping after an apostrophe.

Comment: Where are you printing the buffer? In `endElement()`?

Comment: Try removing the bcomm boolean test from characters. The parser will break up the text into multiple calls to `characters`, since you're setting bcomm to false after the first call, the subsequent calls are not processed.

Comment: Yes 

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            String theFullT = buffer.toString();
            System.out.println(theFullT);
            
            //System.out.println("End Element :" + qName); 
 }

Comment: I've done that but now I've getting all the xml elements, but I only want one particular elements at the moment. I've got the src code from  [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Really appreciate the help

Comment: Set `bcomm=true` when you enter the element you're looking for. Then set it to false when you hit `endElement()`

Comment: Try setting bcomm to false in the endElement when you print the buffer.